# Laravel 4.2 on PHP 7.2 with Mcrypt enabled still shows 'Mcrypt PHP extension required.' on browser

Tags: php, laravel, homestead

I am trying to run a Laravel application (4.2.22) locally with Laravel Homestead 8 that runs on php 7.2 with mcrypt.

I installed mcrypt and enabled it on both php.ini cli and apache2... I have tried everything but my browser still shows "Mcrypt PHP extension required." when I run the application... I was able to even install dependencies (composer install) without showing "mcrypt required"

`php -i | grep "mcrypt"` shows:

```
mcrypt
mcrypt support => enabled
mcrypt_filter support => enabled
```

`php -m` shows mcrypt

Is this something that might have to do with Laravel, Composer or some caching?

Comment: Are you restart apache after installed mcrypt? Are you sure your laravel site use the same php, which you checked? And try to print `phpinfo();` and watch that mcrypt is here too.

Comment: Check your PHP at run time with `phpinfo()`, this could be different to CLI

Comment: Thank you. I just checked phpinfo(); and as you mentioned it is running from /etc/php/7.2/fpm/php.ini  ... How do I enable mcrypt there then? Should I just add extension=mcrypt.so to /etc/php/7.2/fpm/php.ini ?

Comment: Correct, try it. Like you did it in other `.ini` files

Comment: Thank you Grabatui and Scuzzy. I added it to the .ini file and restarted the server. It works on the browser now!

Answer (score 0):

Checked phpinfo() and noticed the server was using etc/php/7.2/fpm/php.ini I added extension=mcrypt.so to the php.ini file and now it is working on the browser.